# What is MomentInput type in ReactJS with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, event-handling, material-ui

I have an event where I recognise if it's a moment date input (material-ui-pickers) or normal text input.

```
const handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  const isDateInput = moment.isMoment(event);
  const dateValue = () => {
   return moment(event).format();
  };
}
```

And I have an error from typescript:

> No overload matches this call.
>
> Overload 1 of 2, '(inp?: MomentInput, format?: MomentFormatSpecification, strict?: boolean): Moment', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type 'ChangeEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MomentInput'.
>         Type 'ChangeEvent' has no properties in common with type 'MomentInputObject'.
>
> Overload 2 of 2, '(inp?: MomentInput, format?: MomentFormatSpecification, language?: string, strict?: boolean): Moment', gave the following error.
>       Argument of type 'ChangeEvent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MomentInput'.
>         Type 'ChangeEvent' has no properties in common with type 'MomentInputObject'.

What type should event have to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add moment.Moment interface like below:

```
const handleInputChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> & moment.Moment) => {
 const isDateInput = moment.isMoment(event);
 const dateValue = () => {
  return moment(event).format();
 };
```

}